# Grafana - How to create sql query part variable/macro for Mysql datasource

Tags: mysql, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have following query in Grafana which is backed by MySql DataSource.

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(ts,$__interval),
  sum(total) AS "total"
FROM hp
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(ts) 
  AND customer_type IN ($CustomerType) AND age IN ($age) AND gender IN ($gender)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(ts,$__interval)
```

There are multiple singleStat/panel/graphs in the Dashboard which use different select parameters but the WHERE condition remains same in all of them.

I want to keep the condition as separate constant variable so that I can add just that variable in every query.

I tried to build my query like this.

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias(ts,$__interval),
  sum(total) AS "total"
FROM hp
$where_condition
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY $__timeGroup(ts,$__interval)
```

and declared `where_condition` as `WHERE $__timeFilter(ts) AND customer_type IN ($CustomerType) AND age IN ($age) AND gender IN ($gender)`.

But the query fails, because the internal variables ($CustomerType,$age,$gender) are not resolved by query generator and generated query looks like this.

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) DIV 900 * 900 AS "time",
  sum(total) AS "total"
FROM hp
ts BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1548311714) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1548398114) 
AND customer_type IN ($CustomerType) AND age IN ($age) AND gender IN ($gender)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) DIV 900 * 900
```

Is there a way to resolve the variables which are contained in other variables. Or Is there any other way to externalise part of query which contains variables?

Comment: Which variable type did you use for `where_condition` and what is your Grafana version?

Comment: Grafana version = v5.4.3, I have used Constant type for `where_condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constant` variable type generates only static string. It didn't substitute any variables. Switch to `query` type and use MySQL to return string, which will have exact string value for your `where_condition` variable. Query:

```
SELECT 'WHERE $__timeFilter(ts) AND customer_type IN ($CustomerType) AND age IN ($age) AND gender IN ($gender)'
```

IMHO: variable substitution should works also for `constant` type. You can open feature request for that https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues.

Comment: It works. I had to disable quotes when using this variable like this `${where_condition:csv}`. I will raise feature request for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with quotes, here is my solution that supports 'All' and many selected:

```
SELECT '
task_run_table.is_system = false 
AND 
(
    ''__all__'' = ''${user:raw}''
    OR 
    task_run_table.user  = any ( string_to_array(''${user:raw}'', '','')::text[])
)
AND 
(
    ''__all__'' = ''${job:raw}''
    OR 
    task_run_table.job_name  = any ( string_to_array(''${job:raw}'', '','')::text[])
)
'
```

`All` value was overridden to `__all__`.
It's used like this:

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroup(task_run_table.start_time, '$interval', NULL),
  task_run_table.name AS metric,
  COUNT(*) AS value
FROM
  task_run_table
WHERE 
  $__timeFilter(task_run_table.start_time) 
  AND 
  ${default_filter:raw}
  AND 
  task_run_table.state = $state
GROUP BY time, task_run_table.name
ORDER BY time, value DESC
```